# How to add discord bots the fastest way?

Tags: bots, discord

Is there an easy way to add a lot of bots into a discord server **without** doing it manually ? (Like a bot will add a lot of bots automaticly).

Comment: You're gonna have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to add bots into a discord server automatically.
Mainly due to these reason(s) :

- Bots can't accept invite links

- From the Discord API documentation(s) [here](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/intro), there is no way to automatically add a bot into a server.

Hence, the only way to add bots to your server is through the common, manual way.
In case you want to know the manual way, basically you just type in this link `https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<BOT_CLIENT_ID>&scope=bot&permissions=0`

Replace `<BOT_CLIENT_ID>` in that link with your Bot's client ID.

The only exception given are to User-bots. But those bots are mostly against the ToS in Discord so I don't recommend you make User-bots.

Comment: This is weird, because a bot (or user) added like, 231 bots in just 5 minutes

Comment: It was like, spamming bots joining

Comment: Check if the bots had a bot tag. Also, the user may be allowed to invite bots to the server, and he made a code to help him invite bots to a server, thats why.

Comment: @WenQin Could you elaborate on user-bots being against the ToS? There is no mention at all of the word "bot" in the ToS (except for viruses), and user-bots are an officially supported feature (as introduced here: https://blog.discordapp.com/the-robot-revolution-has-unofficially-begun-unofficial-api-23a3c722d5bf#.hn6wedvca).

Comment: @dnLL here is the **offical** Discord ToS , https://discordapp.com/tos . In short, if you make yourself, a user, into a bot, it is fine. But if you make yourself a bot **AND** make it respond to others, it is against ToS.

Comment: I fail to see how it is relevant with the official and endorsed bot API...

Answer (score 0):

it is possible, you need a valid invite link for it to work, i asked my friend about this and he said it can be done via `Bot.fetchInvite("Invite")` and then something like `.then(function(e){e.accept()});` but from what he told me its outdated, (this is using discord.js) and in discord C# it can be done easily